# Identifying worded numbers that are grammatically incorrect using NLTK, e.g. "Four hundred two six eight nine",

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

For example, I have a grammatically incorrect sentence like "Forty four six two."

is there a way for me to identify that forty and four is one number, while separating six, two, and forty four from each other so it wont combine to 4426.

and I'd like to know if how im thinking about this whole thing should be different instead (like avoiding the incorrect grammar instead)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You don't need NLP for this one. You just need a context free grammar.

Comment: Would it be like using it to accept or reject the input? im not very familiar with this one.